# What do I win when I implement an interface which is blank?

Tags: java, oop, interface

I have a question regarding "Interfaces" in Java and the question sounds like this:

**What is the use of implementing a blank (empty) interface in my class?**

In order to get a better understanding of the question, I will give you a concrete example:

If you go and see the implementation of "**ArrayList**" class, you will find out that it implements two interfaces (RandomAccess and Cloneable), which are actually totally empty!

Why is that happening?
What do I win by implementing a totally blank interface for my class?

In case you have any ideas, please leave a comment.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those interfaces are called as **Marker interfaces** (*used to mark the class of that type*) and at run time they are used to check the type.

For ex

While running the programm, internal logic may goes like

```
if (yourList instanceof Cloneable) {
        // Hey this object is of type Clonable, please proceed 
    } else {
        // Not that type. Reject
    }
```

Comment: `ObjectOutputStream`  has this kind of check for `Serializable` (marker interface) +1

Comment: @SURESHATTA: Thank you very much for your answer. I have never heard the term "Marker Interface" and that was actually the key. I was a great help.

Answer (score 1):

Those interfaces serve only for differing and identifying instances, consider this:

```
interface MyInterface1 {}
interface MyInterface2 {}
```

Consuming code:

```
if (foo is MyInterface1) ...
```